# ASP.NET MVC - Model.OrderBy Date has no effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, model, sorting, sql-order-by

I'm having some difficulties to sort my results by Date. Is there any special method?
Because I'm doing this right now:

```
var db = new DB();
var articles = db.Articles;
var orderedArticles = articles.OrderBy(a => a.Date);
return View(orderedArticles.ToList());
```

Where Date is a datetime field.
And there is no effect for **OrderBy(..)** or **OrderByDescending(..)**

So I managed to check what is happening.

Everytime I add a new Article I'm just using the date on not the time so
if I have two articles both for the same day for example:
with:

```
var orderedArticles = db.Articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).ToList();
```

I would have

```
Id         Title                           Date
10         First Added  Article            16/09/2009 00:00
11         Second Added Article            16/09/2009 00:00
15         Old Article Added Later         15/09/2009 00:00
```

So you can see that is filtering by date, but the thing is when I have the same date the sorting loses the focus.
So what I did is, orderBy two different contexts like first order by Id and later order by Date:

```
var orderedArticles = db.Articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).ToList();
```

So after this I have the following:

```
Id         Title                           Date
11         Second Added Article            16/09/2009 00:00
10         First Added  Article            16/09/2009 00:00
15         Old Article Added Later         15/09/2009 00:00
```

I really don't know if this is the right way to do it because the main problem is that when you submit a date field like 16/09/2009 it sets the time to 00:00 and this is a problem on this situation.

Comment: Sorry -- I haven't had issues with sorting dates, assuming Date is a datetime field.  Maybe you could be more specific as to your database type / version?

Comment: try moving the OrderBy.  Do: return View(articles.ToList().OrderBy(a => a.Date));  What you are doing looks right, but this will take the database out of the equation and simply use Linq to Objects sorting.  If this works, the sort isn't happening in the linq query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code looks good. You should check what is really in the Date field and make sure you do not for example only set the Date of the DateTime object on the database level, that would result in all DateTime objects of a certain date to point to 00:00:00 thus the LINQ would not know how to sort them.

Comment: Hi Robban is exactly what you said, I've edited my question. But sill, I don't know if this is the right way to do it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the answer you provided (which FYI should be moved into the question as an edit), you should apply a ThenBy, rather than a new OrderBy:

```
var articles = db.Articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).ThenBy(a => a.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: That's cool, thanks for the tip with ThenBy() method Dan, much better like this.