# Why isn't my List<t> sort working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, list, sorting

I have a List that I need to start by date before processing it. This is a child record for a parent record

```
 public class DayRequested
 {
    public int RequestId { set; get; }
    public string DateOfLeave { get; set; }

    public static int CompareDateOfLeave(DayRequested d1, DayRequested d2)
    {
        return d1.DateOfLeave.CompareTo(d2.DateOfLeave);
    }
 }
```

In my controller, I first sort it before processing it. Below are all of the ways I have tried. Note that when I first tried, the uncommented one worked. None of these are changing the order of the List.

```
        //List<DayRequested> requestedDays = requestedDaysIn.OrderBy(o => o.DateOfLeave).ToList();

        requestedDays = requestedDays.OrderBy(o => o.DateOfLeave).ToList();

        //Comparison<DayRequested> comp = new Comparison<DayRequested>(DayRequested.CompareDateOfLeave);
        //requestedDays.Sort(comp);

        //requestedDays.Sort(delegate(DayRequested a, DayRequested b)
        //{
        //    return a.DateOfLeave.CompareTo(b.DateOfLeave);
        //});

        DateTime nextFirstDay = Convert.ToDateTime(requestedDays.First().DateOfLeave);
```

In my list I have:

```
1, 07/10/2013, other info here
1, 07/10/2013, other info here
1, 07/12/2013, other info here
1, 07/12/2013, other info here
1, 07/08/2013, other info here
1, 07/08/2013, other info here
```

What might I be doing wrong? I need the list in date order so that I can properly run some back-end processes in the right order.

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433088/asp-net-mvc-model-orderby-date-has-no-effect?

Comment: @varesa: this problem is unrelated to that one.

Comment: I just read the other Q a second time more carefully, and noticed the same. I did not see at first that the other question was about sorting sorted items...

Comment: I was going to say, I spend 3 hours yesterday scouring the internets looking for why it wasn't working. NEVER seen the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `DateOfLeave` property is a string, and likely stored in this form:

```
7/10/2013
7/8/2013
7/12/2013
```

If you sort these as the strings they are, 7/10 comes before 7/8 since '1' is less than '8'.  To solve this either make your property a`DateTime` or convert it before doing the sort.

Comment: I totally missed that. :-/ Thanks for pointing that out. I converted to `DateTime` before sorting. It works now.